# Не отображается поле с таксономией в записи WordPress

Tags: wordpress

В файле *functions.php* создал новый тип записи *portfolio* и туда же добавил таксономию:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
  function register_post_types(){
  // Регистрируем таксономию для добавления навыков
    register_taxonomy('skills', array( 'portfolio' ), array(
      'label'              => 'Навыки',
      'labels'             => array(
        'name'               => 'Навыки',
        'singular_name'      => 'Навык',
        'search_items'       => 'Найти навык',
        'all_items'          => 'Все навыки',
        'view_item '         => 'Смотреть навыки',
        'parent_item'        => 'Родительский навык',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Родительский навык:',
        'edit_item'          => 'Изменить навык',
        'update_item'        => 'Обновить навык',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новый навык',
        'new_item_name'      => 'Новое имя навыка',
        'menu_name'          => 'Навыки',
      ),
      'description'          => 'Навыки, которые использовались в работе над проектом',
      'public'               => true,
      'publicly_queryable'   => null,
      'hierarchical'         => true,
      'rewrite'              => true,
    ));

    register_post_type('portfolio', array(
      'label'              => 'Портфолио',
      'labels'             => array(
        'name'               => 'Портфолио', 
        'singular_name'      => 'Портфолио', 
        'all_items'          => 'Все работы',
        'add_new'            => 'Добавить работу', 
        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление работы',
        'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование работы',
        'new_item'           => 'Новая работа',
        'view_item'          => 'Смотреть работу',
        'search_items'       => 'Искать работу в портфолио',
        'not_found'          => 'Не найдено',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Портфолио',
      ),
      'description'          => 'Это наши работы в портфолио',
      'public'               => true,
      'publicly_queryable'   => true,
      'show_ui'              => true,
      'show_in_rest'         => true,
      'rest_base'            => '',
      'show_in_menu'         => true,
      'exclude_from_search'  => false,
      'map_meta_cap'         => true,
      'hierarchical'         => false,
      'rewrite'              => true,
      'has_archive'          => 'portfolio',
      'query_var'            => true,
      'supports'             => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
      'taxonomies'           => array( 'skills' ),
      'menu_position'        => 4,
      'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-format-gallery'
    ));     
  }
```

Все это в первый день делал по видеоуроку. В меню только отобразились *навыки*. Добавил несколько навыков и хотел добавить их к портфолио. Но там такого поля не отобразилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал как-то это исправить (самостоятельно, через wp-kama.ru), но ничего не выходило.

Затем на следующий день решил попробовать исправить эту проблему. Зашел на wp-kama.ru, там скопировал пример с регистрацией таксономии и вставил его в *functions.php*. Немного подкорректировал и сохранил.

В итоге появилась возможность добавить навыки к конкретному портфолио и при этом визуально редактор немного поменялся.

Затем возникла необходимость добавить эти же навыки на страницу с записями, изменив строку

`register_taxonomy('skills', array('portfolio'), array(...)`

на строку

`register_taxonomy('skills', array('portfolio', 'post'), array(...)`

И тут снова навыки пропали при добавлении к конкретному портфолио и не появились на конкретной записи, на зато остались в самом меню (как на скриншоте выше).

Удалил таксономию из страницы с постами, но проблема все равно осталась.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Может я что-то делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При регистрации таксономии среди прочих параметров вам нужно передать в функцию `register_taxonomy()` свойство `'show_in_rest' => true`

Т. е. получится

```
register_taxonomy('skills', array( 'portfolio' ), array(
      'label'              => 'Навыки',
      'labels'             => array(
        'name'               => 'Навыки',
        'singular_name'      => 'Навык',
        'search_items'       => 'Найти навык',
        'all_items'          => 'Все навыки',
        'view_item '         => 'Смотреть навыки',
        'parent_item'        => 'Родительский навык',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Родительский навык:',
        'edit_item'          => 'Изменить навык',
        'update_item'        => 'Обновить навык',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новый навык',
        'new_item_name'      => 'Новое имя навыка',
        'menu_name'          => 'Навыки'
      ),
      'description'          => 'Навыки, которые использовались в работе над проектом',
      'public'               => true,
      'publicly_queryable'   => null,
      'hierarchical'         => true,
      'rewrite'              => true,
      'show_in_rest'         => true // вот оно
    ));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все правильно отображается.